# Using Camera by C++/WinRT

Tags: camera, c++-winrt

I want to use Camera(CameraCaptureUI or MediaCapture class) in C++/WinRT.

Microsoft document sample code is written by C# and JavaScript.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI#code-snippet-1

MFC + C++/WinRT

```
void CWinRTtestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonToast()
{
    // show toast
    auto notificationManager = ToastNotificationManager::GetDefault();
    auto toastXml = ToastNotificationManager::GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType::ToastText01);
    auto textNode = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName(L"text").Item(0);
    textNode.AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(L"Hello C++/WinRT!"));
    auto toast = ToastNotification(toastXml);
    toast.ExpirationTime(winrt::clock::now() + std::chrono::hours() * 2);
    notificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}
```

this code is working.

```
IAsyncAction Camera()
{
    auto cameraManager = CameraCaptureUI();
    cameraManager.PhotoSettings().CroppedAspectRatio(Size(4, 3));
    cameraManager.PhotoSettings().Format(CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat::Jpeg);
    auto file{ co_await cameraManager.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode::Photo) };
}

void CWinRTtestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonCamera()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
    auto image = Camera();
}
```

but this code is NOT working...

C++ project setting
Additional Option **/await**
C++ Language Standard **C++17**
Conformance mode **No**

Comment: The problem is not related to C++/WinRT. The problem is that the CameraCaptureUI is supported only from packaged apps (UWP apps), not from desktop apps (which I'm assuming is what you have since you said "MFC").

Comment: @raymond-chen Thank you for your answer. Where can I get that information?(ToastNotificationManager is available, CameraCaptureUI is not available...)

Comment: It's indicated by the absence of the "DualPartition" attribute in the metadata. DualPartition means "can be used by both UWP and desktop apps." But it's also implied by the fact that CameraCaptureUI needs to know what window to display over, and you never told it. For UWP apps, it can call CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread, but desktop apps don't have a CoreWindow. You never did an IInitializeWithWindow or call some other method that provides a window handle.

Answer (score 0):

Teams are slowly adding C++ samples, but it's going to take time. For the most part, a transliteration shouldn't be too hard. If it's a C# constructor, replace it with a C++ constructor. For example:

```
Widget widget = new Widget(123);
```

Becomes:

```
Widget widget(123);
```

Properties don't exist in C++ so you can just add parentheses and treat it as a method. You can also use coroutines, so an `await` in C# becomes a `co_await` in C++.